# How to send a list of items to the watch from PebbleKit for Android

Tags: android, pebble-watch

I have an android app that is essentially a list of timers.  Each timer can have the following fields:

- title (string, can be up to 255 characters)
- id (integer)
- seconds (integer)
- time_started (integer)
- seconds_left (integer)
- running (boolean)
- order (integer)

There can be an unlimited number of these timers, though for the pebble watch app, it'd be ok if I only send the first *n* (10, 15, 20).

Currently I've been sending the items to the watch one at a time, and creating the `PebbleDictionary` like this:

```
private PebbleDictionary buildTimerDictionary(Timer timer) {
    PebbleDictionary data = new PebbleDictionary();
    data.addUint32(C.KEY_ID, timer.getId());
    data.addUint32(C.KEY_SECONDS, (int)timer.getSeconds());
    data.addString(C.KEY_DESCRIPTION, timer.getDescriptionFormatted());
    data.addUint32(C.KEY_TIME_STARTED, (int)timer.getTimeStarted());
    data.addUint32(C.KEY_TIME_LEFT, (int)timer.getSecondsLeft());
    data.addUint8(C.KEY_RUNNING, (byte)(timer.isRunning() ? 1 : 0));
    data.addUint32(C.KEY_ORDER, (int)timer.getOrder());
    data.addString(C.KEY_TIME_DISPLAY, timer.getSecondsFormatted());
    return data;
}
```

And sending it via a queue that sends the next PebbleDictionary to the watch after the previous is acked.

This works, but it's pretty slow.  I feel like I could save a lot of time by packing more than one timer into each message.  However, I'm not sure how to do that, considering the inbox size on the pebble watch itself, and the fact that you have to hard define the keys for the dictionary in appinfo.json (it doesn't seem like you can use arbitrary keys).

How is this sort of thing usually done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

- One message for each item (what you are doing now)
- Multiple items per message.

  - In this case you can pack everything into one value by using byte arrays and concatenating all your fields into the byte array.
  - You can then use the key to send the index of the element in the list.

A few comments:

- Defining the keys in `appinfo.json` is optional and only useful if you are using PebbleKit JavaScript. It has absolutely no use for apps that talk with PebbleKit Android.
- You can query the available buffer size on Pebble with [`app_message_inbox_size_maximum()`](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/group___app_message.html#gad544294c297f3d1941bd94b6b396a24b). Get it when you start your app and send it from Pebble to the Android app.
- The best strategy depends on the average size of your messages. Right now your items will be about 25bytes + the strings + the small overhead of a dictionary (7 bytes + 1 byte per key). If the strings are very small you might fit three items per messages, if the description is very long, you might not be able to send the item at all (you should probably truncate it).